# Array to string conversion - React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an api which is expecting my data to be like the below

```
"item_id" : {
  "0": '145',
  "1":  '356',     
 }
```

But i am submitting a data that looks like but i keep getting array to string conversion. How can i make the structure of my data like the above

```
item_id: Array(2)
0: {item_id: "5a1210d9-cfac-43a0-ae65-3258f118bc8c"}
1: {item_id: "2cf6c7b7-448a-4582-89b2-ed831c2ee2e3"}
```

**COmponent.js**

```
 state = 
    {
      item_id : []
    }

let item_id = this.state.item_id.slice();
var item_id =  parsedData.data.item.id
item_id.push({item_id});
this.setState({ item_id: item_id})
```

Comment: I don't exactly get what is the problem here and what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract just the ID e.g.

```
arr.map(x => x.item_id);
```

Comment: but it will still be an array. Do i have to convert the array to string ?

Comment: @Switzz if the idea is it's to go as part of a JSON API then you call `JSON.stringify({ item_id: myMappedArr })`

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array to an object like:

```js
item_id.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  acc = {...acc, [i]: curr.item_id}
  return acc;
}, {});
```